# VBA Copy row when / if values match *Brain Fried*

Tags: vba

I have a workbook with 2 sheets: `Masterlist` (old data) and `Results` (new data) with unique identifiers in column A.

I'm trying to find a way to copy the row containing the most recent data from the `Results` tab onto the matching row in the `Masterlist` sheet

I have only been able to find a way to copy the new data at the bottom of the `Masterlist`

```
Sub UpdateML()

Dim wM As Worksheet,  wR As Worksheet
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
Dim cel1 As Range, cel2 As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wM = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterList")
Set wR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")

    With wM
    Set r1 = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns("A:A").Column).End(xlUp))
End With

With wR
    Set r2 = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns("A:A").Column).End(xlUp))
End With

On Error Resume Next
For Each cel1 In r1
    With Application
        Set cel2 = .Index(r2, .Match(cel1.Value, r2, 0)) 'find match in Masterlist
        If Err = 0 Then
            copyResult cel2 'copy result to masterlist
        End If
        Err.Clear

End With

Next cel1

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub copyResult(cel As Range)

Dim w As Worksheet, r As Range
Set w = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Masterlist")
Set r = w.Cells(w.Rows.Count, Columns("A:A").Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'next row
cel.EntireRow.Copy w.Cells(r.Row, 1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your copyResult method (when setting the value of r) is picking up the bottom row + 1, so that's why it's being dumped at the bottom of the list.

You have a LastRow variable in the UpdateML method though, which is unused.
I've got it to work by using that as a counter variable to track the row index and passing that into the copyResult method. Like this:

```
Sub UpdateML()
    Dim wM As Worksheet, wR As Worksheet
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Dim cel1 As Range, cel2 As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wM = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterList")
Set wR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")

With wM
    Set r1 = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns("A:A").Column).End(xlUp))
End With

With wR
    Set r2 = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns("A:A").Column).End(xlUp))
End With

LastRow = 1

On Error Resume Next
For Each cel1 In r1
    With Application
        Set cel2 = .Index(r2, .Match(cel1.Value, r2, 0)) 'find match in Masterlist
        If Err = 0 Then
            copyResult cel2, LastRow 'copy result to masterlist
        End If
        Err.Clear
        LastRow = LastRow + 1
    End With
Next cel1
End Sub

Sub copyResult(cel As Range, row As Long)
    Dim w As Worksheet
    Set w = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Masterlist")
    cel.EntireRow.Copy w.Cells(row, 1)
End Sub
```

I'm a little rusty with VBA (not used it in around a year), so there may be more elegant solutions, but this is definitely one option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach.  It uses "Find" which is a little leaner.  It also uses activesheets and cells rather than references.

Do you need to add missing items from Results to the Master list?  This covers that.  If Results col A is the same as MasterList col A this will also work

```
Sub itworks()
'''covers the above
On Error Resume Next ''Can change this to more preferred if error <> 0
Sheets("MasterList").Range("a1").Select
lo = Range("A" & Range("A:A").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Address
Do Until ActiveCell.Address = lo
Sheets("Results").Range("A:A").Find(ActiveCell.Value).EntireRow.Copy ActiveCell''copies found row to your Active Cell
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
Loop
''Adds missing rows
Sheets("Results").Activate
Range("a1").Select
lo2 = Range("A" & Range("A:A").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Address
Do Until ActiveCell.Address = lo2
Set missing = Sheets("MasterList").Range("A:A").Find(ActiveCell.Value)
If missing Is Nothing Then
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("MasterList").Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(1)
End If
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
Loop
End Sub
```